# How to modify multiple CSS attributes of an element?

Tags: css, jsoup

I have to modify multiple CSS attributes of a web page's elements. For example, I want to modify the links element and I have this code:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        links.attr("style", "background-color: yellow");
        links.attr("style", "color:green");
        links.attr("style", "font-size: 40px");
```

My problem is that only the last change is really processed. In this example, that's the the font size. If I delete it, the color change starts working, and so on.

Is there a way to make all those changes in only one method?

Comment: This is because you're effectively over-writing the `style` attribute each time. You probably just want to do something like `links.attr('style', 'background-color: yellow; color: green; font-size: 40px;');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply putting a string in as the style value, so you can do regular CSS notation:

```
links.attr("style", "background-color: yellow; color:green; font-size: 40px;");
```

A better approach might be to simply toggle a CSS class, though:

```
.myClass {
    background-color: yellow; 
    color: green; 
    font-size: 40px;
}

links.addClass('myClass');
```